# Error in using `scipy.integrate.odeint`

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I am using the function `scipy.integrate.odeint`, but I get an unexpected error. My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def hyper_exp_ODE(y, s, λ, k, μ, p):
    F, H = y
    C_bar_s = 1 - (1 - F) **k
    rhs = [-λ * np.sum(p * μ * H) + λ * C_bar_s]
    rhs.extend([-μ[i] * H[i] + C_bar_s for i in range(len(μ))])
    return rhs

def limit_hyper_exp(S, λ, k, N, μ, p):
    S_range = np.linspace(0,S,N)
    y0 = (1-λ, np.zeros(len(μ)))
    sol = odeint(hyper_exp_ODE, y0, S_range, args = (λ, k, μ, p))
    return sol, S_range

S = 10
λ = 0.8
k = 2
N = 100
μ, p = np.array([2.0, 1.2]), np.array([0.2, 0.8])

sol, S_range = limit_hyper_exp(S, λ, k, N, μ, p)
```

And I unexpectedly get the error `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`, I have used very similar code before but instead of vectorizing I explicitly typed everything but this code seemed to be equivalent to me (but is clearly not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
    y0 = (1-λ, np.zeros(len(μ)))
```

That makes `y0` a tuple of length 2 containing a scalar and a numpy array.  When the code in `odeint` tries to convert this to a numpy array, the error occurs.  For example,

```
In [7]: y0 = (1, np.zeros(4))

In [8]: np.array(y0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-9a58cb72863b> in <module>()
----> 1 np.array(y0)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

You could instead create `y0` with something like

```
y0 = [1-λ] + [0]*len(μ)
```

or

```
y0 = np.zeros(len(μ) + 1)
y0[0] = 1-λ
```

Comment: When I do this I get `too many values to unpack (expected 2)` at `F,H = y0`  but this is of course easily solvable by taking `F = y0[0], H = y0[1:]`. Thanks!